# Computing Partial Derivative for RTRL training for Recurrent Neural networks

Tags: java, machine-learning, neural-network

Ok so first off Hi,
Secondly its 3am and I promise you I am fried after spending 3 solid days I understand RNN's and RTRL, but my calculus brain has ran away from me at this point in time.

Basically I'm at the stage where I Need to calculate this:
[image]
More specifically:
[image]

I used a variety of sites and my textbook (which had 0 on this subject), but this is the rest of my primary source [willamette.edu](http://www.willamette.edu/~gorr/classes/cs449/rtrl.html)

The issue I'm having is how to programmatically (Java) partially differentiate
Yk in the direction Wij

I can't wrap my head around how to go about that.
**NOTE: I do actually understand how the RNN and RTRL works, confidently.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not "programmatically (Java) partially differentiate", you do this analyticaly, and implement the simple solution. All these operations are described in **any** neural network related book.

In particular, having `d y_k(t)/d w_ij`. `y_k(t)` is a function of `w_ij` assuming (for simplicity), that this is one layer network then`y_k(t)` is of form `y_k(t) = f( sum w_ij x_j(t) )` (i represent bias as a neuron). So calculating the partial derivative leads to the `f'( sum w_ij x_j(t) ) * x_j(t)`

Before going to RTRL you should first understand simple **backpropagation through time**`, which requires understanding the simple **[backpropagation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation)** first. Then, you can go into RTRL - I recommend following [tutorial](http://minds.jacobs-university.de/sites/default/files/uploads/papers/ESNTutorialRev.pdf).

Comment: It seems I understood a lot less then I thought I did. Thanks. I was actually thinking I should stop trying to be a smartass and just start at the beginning with basic gradient descent.